# cannot set header before they are sent to client error

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am facing error while showing JSON response.

My code is here.

```
app.get('/api/:id/:uid?',(req,res)=>{//? mean optional parameter
    console.log(req.params);// to get parameter in console
    const id=req.params.id*1;
    console.log(id);
    const tour=tours.find(el=>el.id===id);
    res.status(200).json({
        "staus":"success",
        "tours":tour
    })
    res.send("done");
})
```

showing `Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client`

Comment: _"showing cannot set header before they are sent to client"_ - what exactly do you mean by this?  What is the exact symptom you are seeing that you feel is incorrect behavior?

Comment: You cant use `.json` & `.send` at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

I think error message is `Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client`, not `before`. It means that you already sent response back to the client. Just remove `res.send("done");` this line.

But, be careful about other case like below. You'll also get `Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client`.

```js
app.get("/path", (req, res) => {
    some_condition = true
    if (some_condition) {
        res.status(200).json({success: true})
    }
    res.status(200).json({success: false})
})
```

So, you should add `return` in front of `res.status(200).json({success: true})` like below.

```js
app.get("/path", (req, res) => {
    some_condition = true
    if (some_condition) {
        return res.status(200).json({success: true})
    }
    res.status(200).json({success: false})
})
```

Then, it'll not show up `Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client` this error message.